# Enable Node.js Server To Handle Rapid Requests

Tags: node.js, requirejs, overloading

I am developing a web app on my local system and I am currently preparing it for production. We are developing the back end using node.js and developing a web app using require.js. One major issue is that when I visit the app (hosted locally) in my browser, the server will stop responding. Even given a considerable period of time after the server stopped responding, it will not recover and needs to be restarted manually. Obviously, this is not acceptable for production.

I have a suspicion that since the use of require.js is resulting in a very large number of files, requesting these files so rapidly is causing some sort of server overload. Hopefully, we will be able to use r.js on the web app to reduce the requests down to one file.

Is it likely that the use of require.js is causing this to happen? I would have thought that it would still be a relatively low number of requests (although it is over 150 files). Is this a known issue?

Is there a way I can modify my server script to handle this number of requests (even if it takes longer to respond) since, if nothing else, it is hindering development?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

As it turns out, compiling the scripts didn't work, there must be some other problem with my node server. I am not sure what it is that makes the server stop responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found my issue was that the result of a `Math.random()` sometimes resulted in an infinite loop occurring. I am glad it was so easy for me to figure this out.